# angular: tell child component to do something

Tags: angular

I want to access a child component method without using `@ViewChild`

For example: I have a child component and want to tell its parent to `buyFood()` I do this by event emitter

```
child component

 export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  @Output() foodEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  askParentToByFood() {
   this.foodEvent.emit();
  }

  eatFood() {...}
 }
```

parent component

```
 <child-component (foodEvent)="buyFood()"></child-component>
```

assuming we have a `buyFood` function in parent

now my question is how to tell the child component to eatFood from its parent without using @ViewChild.

Comment: using a "reference variable". your child is <child-component #child> and your button in parent <button (click)="child.eatFood()">

Comment: just use `@Input()`'s and @Output()`'s

Comment: using a refrence variable gives an error "Cannot read property 'eatFood' of undefined"

Comment: As mentioned by @Eliseo, refernce variable works. See the stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hildfn-parent?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: In my case it doesn't. I'll post my code tommorow.

Comment: remember that the function must be "public" (by defect, in angular all the functions are public unless you use "private")

Answer (score 0):

To send a value to the child component use an @Input()

```
<child-component isReady="true"></child-component>
```

or

```
<child-component [isReady]="isReady"></child-component>
```

Where isReady is a variable in the parent and an input in the child that you are going to use.

Comment: I don't want to send a value to the child. I want to fire a function in the child from parent

Comment: then use ViewChild and child.DoSomething(); // do not use Output here

Comment: I cant use ViewChild in my case

Comment: why? you are really limiting your options now.